# SR Suntour XCM fork too stiff

Tags: fork, coil

My Rockhopper Comp 27.5 came with the SR Suntour XCM fork (coil) and I want to make it less stiff. I have tried to fully adjust it as far as it goes, but it is still super stiff.

I don’t want to spend more money on air suspension if I’m able to make my current fork less stiff. Also if I can’t fix it, I would like somebody to recommend decent air forks under $150. ($175 max)

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. There are several adjustments to a suspension fork and based on the limited detail you provided, it is possible that the adjustment you made may or may not have been one that adjusts stiffness. Additionally, suspension forks need periodic maintenance to maintain their operation, and it could even be need for that to return or fix a fork that does not allow the desired adjustment. Can you DETAIL the specific adjustment(s) you made in your question to allow us to help you?

Answer (score 2):

The fork normally comes with a spring that it’s on the medium stiffness side. This meaning that it is recommended for people about 60+kg. You can buy new springs for it from the Suntour website, however it would be more beneficial to get a cheap air fork. An air spring is adjustable for any weight and has many more settings.

It is a bit difficult to get a quality air fork for under $175, so I would look on Marketplace for one as you could manage to find something like a RockShox Recon for that price, however you can find some on Amazon for $150 AUD or you can get a low end SR Suntour Epixon for about $120.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to buy a softer spring but they are not a good fork so probably not a good investment.

My product recommendation would be a RockShox set. Even the options at the bottom of the range are a significant upgrade.

Alternatively, a decent air fork may be available second hand if you can find something in good condition if you are confident what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, it is possible to buy a soft spring for those forks. At the low cost involved, I suggest buying a softer string and installing it. If you are happy with that, great, if not, a new fork is called for.

While an Air Shock is likely to be a better fork, and will give you much better adjustability, I do not believe the first approach you try should be buying a new fork.

Buying a new fork also means buying a shock pump (unless you can borrow one while you dial up the right pressure), and having the fork installed. If installing yourself, you will need a range of tools and possibly need to replace the headset (depends on if you can get the race off). You will need a star nut an need to cut down the steerer to size.  No saying doesn't, just saying it is not "just put on a new fork".

A cheap air fork will be no better than the fork you have apart from being adjustable. If you are spending that much money, you probably want more performance than a cheap fork will offer and are setting yourself up to be disappointed.  A used fork can work out, especially if you can get a good fork that are hardly used (owner upgraded to a better one is common), but comes with risks. It is likely to need servicing, so needs to be costed in, and could very easily be unserviceable. If you go used fork, check the steerer is not cut too short for your bike.